# python local modules

Tags: python, python-module

I have several project directories and want to have libraries/modules that are specific to them. For instance, I might have a directory structure like such:

```
myproject/
  mymodules/
    __init__.py
    myfunctions.py
  myreports/
    mycode.py
```

Assuming there is a function called `add` in `myfunctions.py`, I can call it from `mycode.py` with the most naive routine:

```
execfile('../mymodules/myfunctions.py')
add(1,2)
```

But to be more sophisticated about it, I can also do

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../mymodules')
import myfunctions

myfunctions.add(1,2)
```

Is this the most idiomatic way to do this? There is also some mention about modifying the `PYTHONPATH` (`os.environ['PYTHONPATH']`?), but is this or other things I should look into?

Also, I have seen `import` statements contained within class statements, and in other instances, defined at the top of a Python file which contains the class definition. Is there a right/preferred way to do this?

Comment: By your *more sophisticated method*, you are modifying the PYTHONPATH, so, imho, this is the best method

Comment: move `mycode.py` directly into `myproject`

Comment: @Eknath Iyer, you are right... I was not sure if it was preferred to augment the `PYTHONPATH` variable directoy (which is technically different from the search path defined in `sys.path`?). As in `os.environ[PYTHONPATH] += ':../mymodules'` or something.

Comment: @wiso -- yes, that would make sense, but my projects are quite large and have many other (nested) subdirectories which are all meant to call `mymodules`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't mess around with `execfile` or `sys.path.append` unless there is some very good reason for it. Rather, just arrange your code into [proper python packages](http://docs.python.org/distutils/) and do your importing as you would any other library.

If your `mymodules` is in fact a part of one large project, then set your package up like so:

```
myproject/
    __init__.py
    mymodules/
        __init__.py
        myfunctions.py
    myreports/
        __init__.py
        myreportscode.py
```

And then you can import `mymodules` from anywhere in your code like this:

```
from myproject.mymodules import myfunctions
myfunctions.add(1, 2)
```

If your `mymodules` code is used by a number of separate and distinct projects, then just make it into a package in its own right and install it into whatever environment it needs to be used in.

Comment: Thanks -- but I only want to access it through my project, and I want it to be portable such that I only have to move "myproject" to another computer to be able to reproduce it. myreports/ only has to call functions in mymodules/ but not the other way around, so for these reasons I don't want to make a system-wide package.

Comment: My suggestion would make your "myproject" portable without requiring anything but a standard package setup.