# How to resolve "ModuleNotFoundError" No module named 'XXXX'

Tags: python, scrapy, anaconda, spyder

Im working with scrapy, within Spyder/Anaconda environment. I have a project im trying to use the items.py with and no matter what i do, i cant get it to recognize it, keep getting "ModuleNotFoundError"

Here is what i have in my dsg_spider.py and items.py file.
As long as i dont try to use the items.py file within the spider, it runs and works as expected.. Im just trying to get the data in a structured format and want to set it up right before i proceed.

```
import scrapy
import sys
import os
from DSG2.items import Dsg2Item



        doc = Dsg2Item()
        doc['sku'] = response.xpath("//span[@itemprop='sku']/text()").extract()
        doc['price'] = response.xpath("//span[@itemprop='price']/text()").extract()
        doc['description'] = response.xpath("//meta[@itemprop='name']/@content").extract()
```

File "F:/Anaconda/DSG2/DSG2/spiders/dsg_spider.py", line 4, in 
    from DSG2.items import Dsg2Item

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DSG2'

This is the code within the items.py

```
import scrapy

class Dsg2Item(scrapy.Item):
     description = scrapy.Field()
     sku = scrapy.Field()
     price = scrapy.Field()
#brand = brand
#description = name
```

The folder structure where i have all my files

```
Anaconda (folder)
   DSG2 (folder)
   |---DSG2 (folder)
       |---_pycache_ (folder)
       |---spiders (folder)
           |---_pycache_ (folder)
           |---_init_.py (file)
           |---dsg_spider.py (file)
       |---_init_.py (file)
       |---items.py (file)
       |---middlewares.py (file)
       |---pipelines.py (file)
       |---settings.py (file)
   |---scrapy.cfg (file)
```

Comment: Your folder structure looks odd, are you sure it is indented properly?

Comment: im not sure how to get it to look correctly, i manually typed it based on my folder structure, so im sure its not correctly formatted

Comment: i tried to update it now so it reads a little better

Comment: It looks like you are missing some `__init__.py` files to make this structure acceptable for module imports.  There are some quality answers to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732685/python-local-modules

Comment: Looking at the examples on that link and my folder structure, i do have the _init_.py files within the folders. There is one within the DSG2 folder and then there is one within the Spiders folder and both files have nothing in them.

Comment: I do not see one in the highest `DSG2` directory.  Also, your `_init_.py` have only 1 underscore where there should be 2.

Answer (score 1):

The solution as it seems for me was to within Spyder, go to Projects --- New Project --- Select Existing directory then navigate to the project folder and select create, that created a project and when i run it, it no longer complains..

Answer (score 0):

I think your forgot to add your package to the pythonpath.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/your/package_or_module")
```

Comment: how do you mean?     i have this variable setup  PYTHONPATH=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3       and at some point today our IT dept is going to add that to my "Path" variable