# Can't import local module in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a directory structure like this:

```
|-- top-level-directory/
  |-- django-app/
    |-- some-app/
      |-- models.py
      |-- ...
    |-- some-other-app/
      |-- ...
  |-- local-module/
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- ...
  |-- other-directory-with-scripts/
    |-- file-where-import-works-fine.py
```

In some-app/models.py, I have an `import local-module` statement. However, I get an error saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'local-module'`.

I can import the module in other scripts outside the django directory without any problems. Any idea why this could be happening or how I can fix it?

Comment: Using hyphens (`-`) is not allowed as far as I know.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the module name doesn't actually have a dash in it, I used it just as an example.

Comment: Can you give real file structure? That would help us.

Comment: @Hisham___Pak  the only files I didn't write down are views.py, urls.py and such in the django app and files that contain my code in the module.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python local modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732685/python-local-modules)

Comment: @KristínaSzabová Can you try : from . import local_module